# How to "select where" in Mapper Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my source code:

```
<select id="selectById" resultMap="BaseResultMap" parameterType="rml.model.MUser">
SELECT 
<include refid="Base_Column_List" />
     From MUSER where 1 = 1 
  <if test="name != null" >
    and Name = #{name,jdbcType=VARCHAR} 
  </if>
  <if test="age != null" >
   and age = #{age,jdbcType=DECIMAL}
  </if>
```

but when i run this code, it return null with every paramaster.
when i remove

```
    <if test="name != null" >
    and Name = #{name,jdbcType=VARCHAR} 
  </if>
  <if test="age != null" >
   and age = #{age,jdbcType=DECIMAL}
  </if>
```

it return a list

Can you help me fix this code ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is value of `name` and `age` and is there any records which matched the `name` and `age?`

Comment: @Forward value of name: string, age: int, i sure that i typing value of field is right

Comment: Is the column name 'age' begin with lower case 'a'? Shouldn't it be 'Age' instead?

Comment: @fluffyBatman yes. column name 'age' begin with lower case 'a'

Comment: @Tuan-IT Do you have any log component in your system which logged sql in run time? You can not just be sure about that, cause here has no exception, it just has no result, you should confirm if you parameters are correct or not.